# AWS API Gateway Custom Authorizer is not invoked when executing API Method

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I'm using AWS lambda serverless WEB API application. My controller having one method that simply returns some string value. I want to add an authentication layer which authenticates the requester. The requester should pass "Authorizer" key to the header to authenticate.

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html) article help me to do so. I used this [example](https://github.com/RecursiveLoop/GrandmasRecipes).

I created one Custom Authorizer lambda which authenticates the user passed in the header of API request. Buth my Custom Authorizer is not calling when I hit API URL. Below is my Custom Authorizer lambda function code

```
public APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse FunctionHandler(APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequest apigAuthRequest, ILambdaContext context)
    {


        Console.WriteLine("1");

        bool ok = false;

        if (apigAuthRequest.Headers["Authorization"] == "test")
        {
            ok = true;
            Console.WriteLine("2");
        }
        return new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerResponse
        {
            PrincipalID = "test",
            PolicyDocument = new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy
            {
                Version = "2012-10-17",
                Statement = new List<APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy.IAMPolicyStatement>() {
                  new APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerPolicy.IAMPolicyStatement
                  {
                       Action = new HashSet<string>(){"execute-api:Invoke"},
                       Effect = ok ? "Allow" : "Deny",
                       Resource = new HashSet<string>(){ apigAuthRequest.MethodArn } // resource arn here
                  }
            },
            }
        };

    }
```

I'm expecting that this function should call when I invoke my API.

Below is the screenshot of AWS Console --> API Gateway where I configured custom authorizer for my API.

[image]

[image]

Why my authorizer is not called when I hit API URL.

Comment: How do you know it is not called? What do you expect to see? and what's the actual response?

Comment: How do you know it is not called -- There should be cloudwatch logs when authorizer lambda function called. But no logs there.
What do you expect to see -- I'm expecting that my API should not return output if custom-authorizer is not valid or Deny.
what's the actual response -- API controller method return a string value. But as custom-authorizer is placed, it should not return string value if custom-authorizer return Deny response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Custom authorizers start to work only after you deploy a stage. Make sure you deployed yours.

Comment: Arghhh.... How I missed it!!!.. I forgot to deploy it. And after deploy it works for me.

Comment: Awesome! Good to hear :)